# How to redirect on error page if the id parameter in url does not match the one in database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I Have a MERN stack application which uses Axios library to establish the connection between the client and the server. I have a route '/blogs' which fetches all the blogs from the backend and displays it on the interface. Then there's a dynamic route '/blogs/:id' if the id passed in the id parameter matches the one in the database, that specific blog should be rendered. Which it does pretty nicely. My problem is that when I pass any other thing in the id parameter that does not match an id in the database, it should redirect the user to an error 404 page. But instead of that it displays nothing but a navbar as if it went on to render the single blog page anyways regardless of weather the server sent a blog or not. And I get this error in my server console.

```
D:\Projects\vite\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4913
  const castError = new CastError();
                    ^

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "dsfgfsf" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Blog"
    at model.Query.exec (D:\Projects\vite\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4913:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (D:\Projects\vite\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:5012:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"dsfgfsf"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'dsfgfsf',
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
      at new BSONTypeError (D:\Projects\vite\server\node_modules\bson\lib\error.js:41:28)
      at new ObjectId (D:\Projects\vite\server\node_modules\bson\lib\objectid.js:67:23)
      at castObjectId (D:\Projects\vite\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:25:12)
      at ObjectId.cast (D:\Projects\vite\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:246:12)
```

So what I think It is expecting in the id parameter is a string that is the same length of an object id that mongodb documents automatically are assigned. Anyway's here's my code.

```
export const getSingleBlog = async (req, res) => {
    
        const singleblog = await blog.findOne({ _id: req.params.id})
        if(!singleblog) {
            res.send("No Blog Found for real")
        } else {
            res.send(singleblog);
        }
}
```

This function is called back when a get request is made to '/blogs/:id' endpoint.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar/Navbar'
import axios from 'axios'
import './SingleBlog.css'
import Error404 from '../Error404/Error404'

const SingleBlog = () => {

    const {id} = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [blog, setBlog] = useState({});

    const fetchBlog = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/blogs/${id}`);
        setBlog(response.data);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchBlog();
    }, []);
    
    if (blog) {    
        return (
            <>
        <Navbar title="PEGASUS" op1="Compose" op2="About Us" op3="Contact Us" />

        <div className="blog" key={blog._id}>

            <h1>{blog.blogTitle}</h1>
            <br />

            <main>
                <p>{blog.content}</p>
            </main>

            <div className="author">
                <h4>- {blog.author}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
  )
} else return (
    <Error404 />
)
}

export default SingleBlog
```

And this is the react code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue stems from here:

`req.params.id`

You need to perform a check to tell whether or not it's a number, and then tell `Express` what to do when `id` is not a number before `Mongo` gets the bad input.

There's a few ways to handle this but you might try is using the  [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) check:

```
const { id } = req.params;

if (isNaN(id)) {
  throw new Error('id is not a number');
} else {
  res.send();
}
```

Then your frontend component would want to catch this error being thrown and deal with it somehow:

```
const fetchBlog = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/blogs/${id}`);
    setBlog(response.data);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of isNaN use `Number.isInteger(+id)` where the + operator converts a string to a number and isInteger tests to see if the number is an integer. isNaN would return true for 1.2

Comment: Why do I have to do a number test thought? Because mongodb objectid is a BSON data type i read somewhere.

Comment: `reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer` --- I don't think `"dsfgfsf"` conforms to any of those standards --- https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/